# number_format in a number_format doesn't work

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm having trouble with a tiny code in php:

```
$price = 135;
$price_sale = number_format($price * 0.75,2,',','');
//*returns 101,25 *//
$count_products = 3;
$new_price = number_format($price_sale * $count_products,2,',','');
//* returns 303,00 and not 303,75 *//
```

How can I fix this problem?

Regards,

Frank

Answer (score 8):

Keep numbers as numbers. Don't format until the output stage.

Answer (score 5):

Never do `number_format` on numbers you want to do calculations with.

`101,25` is not a valid number in PHP.

Work with the raw values until the number is output. *Then*, do a `number_format()`.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$new_price = number_format($price * 0.75 * $count_products,2,',','');
```

as `$price_sale` is a `string` and won't probably have the value you're calculating with, after type casting. (See: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: Ok thanks!Pretty stupid by me. Didn't know that number_format has to output at last.